# Setup proxy for tox in tox.ini

Tags: python, pytest, tox, napalm

I'm a newbie in the tox library. I failed to run tox
[image]

and this is my tox.ini
[image]

It seems the proxy configuration is failed.
[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I never had to use a proxy for `tox` / `pip`, but after reading https://leifengblog.net/blog/how-to-use-pip-behind-a-proxy/ I would suggest to try two things...

a) lower case the environment variable to `https_proxy`

b) pass in the proxy command to `pip` similar like `sudo pip install --proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port somepackage`

I'd go with the second approach, as one commenter in above blog post mentioned the `environment variable approach` did not work for him on Linux.

Also see here the [official pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server).

Comment: Thanks for your support! I can install the library using pip with proxy but cannot with tox

Answer (score 0):

I am the author/maintainer of the tox. If you're using tox 3.14.4 or later you don't need to specify the environment variables - see https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/commit/33fd18be87ba9eed85f7767e20abce0c90fffe4e

You should not need to change anything with a recent version of pip/tox. I'm using tox from behind a proxy on a daily basis.

> I can install the library using pip with proxy but cannot with tox

Can you detail both of these? How you do it?

PS. We have a discord chat if you'd like a more interactive help channel https://discord.gg/tox

Comment: PS D:\projects\napalm-aos> pip install future
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\vmtri2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\future-0.18.2-py3.9.egg (0.18.2)                  so sorry I don't know how to add the capture in comment. I can use pip to install library. my company is using the proxy has address 10.10.10.10:8080 currently. i am using tox 3.22.0

Comment: pip install --proxy http://10.10.10.10:8080 future
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\vmtri2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\future-0.18.2-py3.9.egg (0.18.2).

Comment: yeah, I got it. It needs to set proxy into the setenv in tox.ini file. Thank you so much

Comment: you only need to set that if your host shell does not have the proxy set (assuming you're using 3.14 and later)